# Wireless disabled on 12.10 Macbook pro 7.1

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook-pro, ubuntu-12.10, wifi-driver

I have a Mac book pro 7,1 and triple booted it by (OSX10.6,Windows7,Ubuntu12.10) every 3 OS boots normally and everything is ok. Just Ubuntu does not recognize my Wireless

According to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Quantal#Wireless_.28AirPort.29) I should have something under Additional Drivers, but the box is empty.

I used the lspci command or lsusb command on terminal no wireless (broadcom) driver shows up.

Comment: check the wifi switch to start red usually means the safety is off :-)